# Support for Asus Z97-pro?

Tags: asus

I'm in the process of configuring a machine which will be used to run Ubuntu, with Windows through virtualization. Does anyone have experience with this motherboard, and is able to tell me whether this is going to work, including the integrated wifi? Is it doable, or should I better try another board?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/503168/minor-problems-with-using-an-asus-z97-a-motherboard

Answer (score 3):

I decided to build a system.  After a lot of research I bought the list of hardware below.  In trying to decide which motherboard to select, I sent emails to ASUS and Gigabyte, both of whom took a long time to reply.  Their replies were nothing more than a Google search with a hit listing Ubuntu and one of their mother boards in the article, both of which I had already run across.  I decide to go with ASUS.  I am not a gamer and am not interested in over-clocking, so I kept my hardware selection simple.  I could have spent much less or a lot more on the hardware, but I simply wanted to build a dependable machine.  I got most of my stuff from NewEgg.com, but I did buy some from Micro Center, who had some impressive sales prices the day I went in.

ASUS Z97 Pro motherboard with LGA 1150 socket – was easy to install, nice UEFI BIOS screens. 
Intel Core i7 4790 Chip – not the ‘K’ version, as I am not interested in over-clocking for my testing. 
Seasonic G650 80 Plus Gold Power Supply – runs cool and is very quiet. 
Corsair Vengeance Memory , 16Gb – 2 x 8Gb DDR3. Mother Board defaulted it to 1333Mhz, had to change the BIOS to 1600Mhz. 
Samsung 850 EVO SSD – real fast. 
Western Digital 1Tb, 7200RPM HDD. 
TP-Link PCIe wireless card – model TL-WDN3800 – worked right out of the box, no tweaks necessary.  I went with this add-on card because I read several reviews of the integrated wireless being unreliable. 
Corsiar SPEC-02 Mid Tower – comes with 2 fans and front USB3 ports. 
No Video card – as mentioned I’m not a gamer, so I just used the Intel video. There is room for a big video card if desired, but you probably would want a bigger power supply to drive it. 
Downloaded Linux from Distrowatch.com – see the right side of the page and choose a flavor.  I went with Ubuntu 14.10. 
Borrowed the Keyboard, mouse, speakers and DVD from another system I had.

The hardware installation went very well and pretty easy.  Watch a couple YouTube videos (NewEgg TV had some good ones) on how to install the hardware and read the directions to do it correctly.  Everything worked together from the start.  I have not had to go hunting for drivers.  The UEFI BIOS took some effort to figure out.  At this time, Ubuntu has been running fine for several weeks.  I used KVM to build a virtual machine that is running Windows7 (simultaneously, not a dual boot), also running fine.  Both boot up in about 10 seconds.

Hope this was helpful.  Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

When searching Z97 Topic: From what I have gathered from others posts and answers. (And referenced Bugs links in those posts.) There is a kernel fix being implemented in 14.10 (But not retroactively in 14.04.1 LTS ? ..Well, I hope the kernel fix is implemented there also, so that users don't have to sacrifice LTS just to have it.)
In the meantime. I think the Bug workarounds might be best summed up in this:

How to fix Ubuntu hardware compatibility issues on an Intel Z97 chipset computer build
https://github.com/Nerdylicious/How_To_Fix_Ubuntu_Compatibility_On_Intel_Z97_Build

As to virtualizing Windows: There is an odd UEFI behaviour in Win7 that prevents this, but which seems to not occur with Win8.1

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7702