# Ubuntu 15.04 UEFI cannot install - Blank Screen (No Signal.)

Tags: nvidia, uefi, 15.04

As the title says, I go to boot into either the live session with Ubuntu 15.04 or the "Install Ubuntu" option and both give me no video at all. I've the onboard VGA and still nothing. The only thing I can think of here is the motherboard which is an ASUS Z97-A motherboard or possibly the graphics card (which unfortunately I don't have any others laying around that I  could test right now.)

Full specs: 
**Power Supply** - *EVGA 850W SuperNova 80+ Gold*
**Motherboard** - *Asus z97-A*
**CPU** - *Intel i7 4790k 4.0 GHz (No OC)*
**Graphics** - *EVGA NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 SC*
**RAM** - *Corsair 16GB (4x4)*
**Storage** - *Samsung 850 EVO Pro 120 GB (SSD)*

Any ideas?

**EDIT** I resolved the issue by pressing 'e' from the UEFI menu and then adding 'nomodeset', after that I was able to install Ubuntu 15.04 (however it was in 640x480 resolution so I had to keep dragging around the window.) After the install I was greeted with no signal once again, so I went into the recovery mode on the boot selection screen and selected 'resume', from there I installed the nvidia-346 drivers from the xorg-edgers ppa and rebooted and my problem was solved! :D. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I have an Asus z97-AR which uses the same UEFI as yours. But have only an older nVidia GT620 which I have not even installed the proprietary nVidia drivers for. Have you tried nomodeset?  There have been issues with the newest Maxwell nVidia, but I thought kernel, support software & drivers were updated and 15.04 should work. I did have to change many settings in UEFI. Turn off fast boot. make sure on cold reboot that normal start up is the setting. Otherwise you may have issues getting into UEFI. Later, I kept cold boot at normal so I would have full reset and time to get into UEFI.

Comment: Another Asus Z97A thread. http://askubuntu.com/questions/503168/minor-problems-with-using-an-asus-z97-a-motherboard Only with secure boot or Windows off and UEFI only could I get my AR to boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I had tried every setting recommended with the UEFI settings. Not sure how to use nomodeset with the UEFI installer either so I haven't tried that yet. 
The only other thing is that for whatever reason I can install anything below ubuntu 14.10, as 14.04 works and linux mint 17 works fine as well, I just get that same issue where it's a black screen with no signal, however my USB devices like my mouse and keyboard are lit up as if they are working, just no video.
So how exactly do I enable nomodeset with the UEFI installer?
Thanks!

Comment: With UEFI you get grub menu on installer. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.

Comment: That worked, was able to install... and then I got a black screen again with no signal. So I went into recovery mode from the boot option screen, and then went to resume which I was able to get video (in 640 x 480 resolution -.-,) so from there I just added the xorg edgers ppa and installed the nvidia-346 driver, rebooted, and now it's working :D. Seemed like it was my graphics driver after all.
Thanks a bunch for the nomodeset detail, will have to remember that for future installations like this.