# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 on two SSD + two HDD

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I plan to build a desktop machine with Ubuntu 14.04LTS/Windows 7 Pro dual boot. I want to use 2 SSD drives (250GB x2), one for each operating system. Then I use 2 7200RPM HDD drives (1TB x2) to store user files for each operating system.

According to my previous experience on laptop, I will install windows 7 first with C partition in SSD, and D partition in HDD. Then I continue to install Ubuntu on the other SSD and mount my home directory on HDD. Is that a correct plan?

RMK: Currently, my plan is to buy Asus Rampage Black Edition motherboard, Intel i7 Core 4930K CPU, Nvidia 980 gtx GPU, 16GB RAM.  Any suggestions?

---

Update: I am not sure if Asus mother board fully support Ubuntu. I searched online, most people just install Windows on it. Did anyone has this motherboard with dual boot?

Comment: I mainly use Ubuntu for programming and learning GPU computing, and use Windows for 3D gaming.

Comment: IF that new of system, you need to install in UEFI mode to take advantage of that. You do have to slightly modify the Windows installer as it defaults to BIOS mode. My Asus z97-ar required a lot of UEFI/CSM settings to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. You may have more issues with nVidia 980 as that need very newest versions of just about everything. http://askubuntu.com/questions/615896/ubuntu-15-04-uefi-cannot-install-blank-screen-no-signal?noredirect=1#615896 And if UEFI, all drives need to be gpt partitioned.

Comment: @oldred: Thank you! I call Asus customer support, they said this motherboard don't support drivers for linux. I guess I need to change a different one

Comment: None of the manufacturers will say they directly support Linux. And none do drivers. All the drivers are included with LInux, but very new systems may not be fully supported since vendors are not helping the open source developers. Even Intel that does help takes a while for new updates to be in kernel and then that new kernel to be in a standard distribution. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2063073 Older version with last post on newer Rampage.

Comment: @oldfred: I did some search online. I found another board which has been tested on Linux: MSI X99S SLI Plus.  Now I incline to choose this motherboard instead, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good plan.  I have dual booted Linux with Microsoft Windows in the past, and it has worked just fine.  That also sounds like a good computer your building.  Should be very fast!
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! But I am not quite sure if the motherboard support ubuntu or not. It seems not many people do that.

Comment: If you're wondering about drivers, Ubuntu 95% of the time automatically detects the hardware on the motherboard (sound, network, etc.) with no other installations required. If your just wondering if your motherboard will work with Ubuntu, it should.  The motherboard should work with Ubuntu like it would any other operating system.

Comment: Yes, I just worry if Ubuntu can detect and support Asus Rampage black edition motherboard. I found online someone claimed that he had trouble to install Ubuntu on it.  Currently, I prefer to choose MSI X99S SLI Plus. It has X99 chipset instead of X79 chipset of the black edition motherboard.