# Ubuntu Install crashes after Grub

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I just built 2 new computers based on [this part list](http://pcpartpicker.com/user/bpowers/saved/xH2G3C).

Notable Changes: Motherboard was upgraded to a [Maximus 8 impact](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813132638&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Intel+Motherboards-_-N82E16813132638&gclid=CjwKEAiAmeyxBRCJxoKk7IWLl2oSJABvZjhhHZQW220sEhsrtwtVn6_W0Z7N0Y2JVaUxzOClrL4emxoC3kTw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)
and CPU was upgraded to [Intel Core i7-6700K](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117559)

I have 3 of the builds noted in the PC part picker and all run ubuntu better than any other machine I've ever used. The new PC's however seem to crash after grub when I try to install from a linux USB. The USB has been confirmed with other computers and works fine. But with my new PC's once I select either "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" the computer drop connection with the monitor. It still appears to be on but I can't do anything with it.

Any ideas as to what is going on? thanks.

Comment: What video are you booting with? Intel Or an add in video card. Skylake needs this boot parameter:  i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 If nVidia or AMD, you need nomodeset to boot in low quality graphics until you install the proprietary drivers. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Another 970, but different motherboard: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615896/ubuntu-15-04-uefi-cannot-install-blank-screen-no-signal?noredirect=1#615896

Comment: Thanks for this I was able to boot from the flash drive.  However I am unable to detect the harddisk in the computer, and so am unable to proceed with the installation. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l`. Does gparted show partitions correctly? Since new UEFI system, you will want gpt and should use UEFI. IF also installing Windows drive must be gpt partitioned for UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for OldFred for helping me solve this.  The solution was to replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" in the grub.