# UEFI dual boot on Windows 10 Pro + installing NVDIA graphics driver (HP Envy 15t)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, hp, nvidia-geforce

Tried bunch of stuffs. Now, if someone could suggest a good method I want to uninstall what I installed without effecting windows and do a clean install following the right procedure.

Purpose is to use Ubuntu as platform for developing deep learning Python/C++ applications using NVIDIA GPU (Geforce GTX 950M).

What I did:
1. Created USB stick with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for installation (at that point I did not know about booting in UEFI mode; all I did was change the order in BIOS). By the way my BIOS is in UEFI mode.
2. Tried installing NVDIA graphics driver and lost GUI screen. Restored it back later though by going to the original driver.
3. Tried number of things to fix the dual boot issue. (If I remember correctly, I think it had worked for the first time and then onwards it does not normally. I can do F9 everytime and then boot either or but I wish to make it through Windows or GRUB boot loader).

Please suggest. Thanks!

EDIT:
I believe oldfred's solution and guide will work. I haven't tried it yet but I will update this post as I get that done. (In the mean-time feel free to add in).

Comment: You want to be sure to install in UEFI boot mode. How you boot installer is how it installs. And do not install nVidia .run but from Ubuntu repository or ppa if very newest driver required. But HP has issues booting anything other than Windows. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair and adding nomodeset: http://askubuntu.com/questions/615896/ubuntu-15-04-uefi-cannot-install-blank-screen-no-signal?noredirect=1#615896

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to make sure to do it in UEFI mode: So, installling method is fine so far: 1) create USB 2) boot in USB UEFI mode 3) and install. It's the part after this that I am not sure about; to be able to keep the dual boot menu intact forever. [Right now I am trying to clean everything except Windows from my previous install]. So far got the bcd restored now trying to delete grub that is still there after i deleted the Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

To boot grub first:

(Usually F1 to enter BIOS)
Locate UEFI / Legacy boot order in your BIOS. Set to legacy first.
(It seems you have installed Legacy)

If that does not help locate boot order and move your ubuntu disk to the top (Or under USBkey).

If this fails you might consider:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Please read the whole article.

Comment: I do not want to go to Legcy mode and want to remain in UEFI mode. I am sorry if I misunderstood your statement.

Comment: If drive is gpt and you install in CSM/BIOS/Legacy boot mode, you can use Boot-Repair to convert from CSM to UEFI. All it really does is uninstall grub-pc (BIOS) and install grub-efi-amd64(UEFI).

Comment: Hi oldfred, I assume my drive is gpt (I am saying because it has EFI partion; I am not exactly sure what will make a drive gpt). I think I understand what you are saying but can you share a link that will guide me through the process. I would guess the overall steps will be to: 1)Change BIOS to legacy mode 2) Boot using USB and install Ubuntu 3) Use Boot-repair to convert back to UEFI mode. Correct? Also, I do not want to put my Windows 10 and data partition into risk.