# Dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu) skips BIOS and Grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

Recently I have installed Ubuntu on a partition using Disk Management on Windows 10. Then I was able to login to Ubuntu but it would skip both BIOS and Grab screens. Before the installation I have disabled both Hibernate and Fast Boot and I would see BIOS screen.

Then I edited my Grub file by setting Windows 10 to default boot and now I cannot access Ubuntu. Since changing Grub file changed my default boot to Windows, I am guessing that the error comes from Ubuntu side.

And I've tried setting default boot loader to Grub:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

But that also gave no effect. Also sometimes when booting, if I press `SHIFT` the screen stays black until I manually shut down and power on again.

Comment: You cannot install (Full) Ubuntu to partition created by Windows. What brand/model system? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: When I was installing, I chose "Something else" instead of "install along Windows Boot manager". So I think I need to reinstall. Do I have to restore Windows Boot Manager before clearing the partition for Ubuntu?

Comment: If Windows 10 came with system, not upgrade from Windows 7, then you can just in UEFI select Windows. If you just used Windows to shrink the NTFS and then use Something Else to create a / (root) ext4 partition your install should be ok. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Here is Boot Repair pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/26223700/

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. If you hold shift key from BIOS does grub menu appear?

Comment: If I do that the screen stays black indefinitely until I put power off and on.

Comment: Did you try the shift key (since BIOS boot) to get into grub menu? Best not to power off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power  If black screen: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: For some reason I can choose OS at boot but the screen is black during OS selection. So for now I just need to remember the position of OS which I can access using arrow keys.

Comment: See if any of these fixes work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it What brand/model system and what video card/chip?

Comment: I got i5-4690K and Asus Z-97a. I was able to resolve the issue by clearing CMOS and I found out that fast boot was enabled even after I disabled on Windows. The only issue now is that I get both Windows Boot Manager and then Ubuntu Grub.

Comment: I have a Z97-ar which is same UEFI. I had to make a lot of setting changes in UEFI. See these: Minor problems with using an ASUS Z97-A Motherboard
http://askubuntu.com/questions/503168/minor-problems-with-using-an-asus-z97-a-motherboard & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/554735/good-z97-motherboard-for-ubuntu  Asus z97 screenshots:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=297