# Ubuntu 19.10 Installer Fails to Boot on Z97A

Tags: grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I downloaded the official Ubuntu ISO for version 19.10 and I used unetbootin to burn the USB stick.

https://unetbootin.github.io/

I was able to get to the grub bootloader, and I was able to choose the Live Disk option.

Then my screen turned light black and hung for over thirty minutes. My keyboard lights go dark.

My hardware is running on a standard Z97A motherboard.

https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97A/

I had previously booted Debian from USB and installed it was well as other operating systems.

lubuntu similarly fails to boot.

I had tried Ubuntu in failsafe mode, and I had tried both the standard and failsafe installer modes as well. All give me the same black screen.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO download was perfect? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and probably more important the write to your install media was flawless? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)  Note: CD refers to CD/DVD/thumb-drive/ssd/hdd or whatever media you wrote ISO to; ie. use the "*Check disc for defects*" option; what release of Lubuntu?  what release(s) of debian (what age, 19.10 is very recent?  Debian Bullseye (11), Buster (10) or how old?

Comment: My Asus Z97-AR works (same as yours, different video ports), but I do make multiple UEFI settings changes. What video card/chip? Asus z97 screenshots:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258575&page=2 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/503168/minor-problems-with-using-an-asus-z97-a-motherboard If black screen is it nVidia? Then you need nomodeset. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I solved this by plugging into the built in video card, and using that to install Ubuntu. Then I plugged back in my Geoforce 740 Nvidia card. Ubuntu 19.10 booted normally using my Nvidia card.